# Layered navigation and category submenu

Tags: magento

I have a site with the top category menu, when you hover it displays a submenu with two columns: "By categories" and "By brands"

Currently "By categories" works perfectly showing a list of subcategories, but "By brands" have a bug. When is not filtered by any brand, shows the list of brands, but when I select one brand in the layered navigation or submenu (which is a link to the layered navigation filter), the brands stop seen.

How can i do to show a list of brands in each submenu? Not all brands have results on every category, thats why i use de Layered Navigation Filter code.

This is the code for catalog/navigation/top.phtml:

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$brands = array();
$_childCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($categoryChildId);
$layer->setCurrentCategory($_childCategory);

$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'brand') {
        $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('catalog/layer_filter_attribute')
                ->setLayer($layer)
                ->setAttributeModel($attribute)
                ->init();

        foreach ($result->getItems() as $option) {
            $brands[$option->getValue()] = $option->getLabel();
        }
    }
}
var_dump($brands);
```